# Save as_kable_extra (format = "latex") on file

Tags: r, latex, kableextra, gtsummary

I use `as_kable_extra(table, format="latex")`.
This code gives me a chuck of latex codes, then I copy and paste then save it as a tex table.

Can I save the latex code on R so that I can avoid copy and paste?

Answer (score 3):

I would save the table latex code to a file.

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.0'

trial %>%
  select(age, grade) %>%
  tbl_summary() %>%
  as_kable_extra(format = "latex") %>%
  readr::write_lines(file = "latex_table.tex")
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Then when you're writing your latex document, include the saved latex table using the `\input{}` command.

```
\input{latex_table.tex}
```