# Generate summary statistics by subgroup with stargazer

Tags: r, summary, stargazer

I try to generate a summary statistics table for latex in R with `stargazer`. The table should contain the summary statistics sorted by three subgroups (Rwanda/Honduras/Nepal).

It worked out fine, when I did seperate tables only for the subgroup. I thought maybe the country variable is the problem.

The `all_summary` data frame looks like this:

```r
structure(list(country = structure(c("Honduras", "Nepal", "Rwanda"
), label = "Country", format.stata = "%8s"), headGender = structure(c(0, 
1, 0), label = "head_gender", format.stata = "%9.0g"), femaleEduc = structure(c(1, 
2, 2), label = "female_educ", format.stata = "%9.0g"), maleEduc = structure(c(1, 
1, 2), label = "male_educ", format.stata = "%9.0g"), wVispeople = structure(c(0, 
1, 0), label = "w_visitpeople", format.stata = "%9.0g"), wVismarket = structure(c(0, 
1, 1), label = "w_vismarket", format.stata = "%9.0g"), wLeavevill = structure(c(0, 
1, 0), label = "w_leavevill", format.stata = "%9.0g"), fridge = structure(c(1, 
0, 0), label = "fridge_owned_desired", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    radio = structure(c(1, 1, 1), label = "radio_owned_desired", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    fan = structure(c(0, 0, 0), label = "fan_owned_desired", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    pc = structure(c(0, 0, 0), label = "pc_owned_desired", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    tv = structure(c(1, 0, 1), label = "tv_owned_desired", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    minutesSolid = structure(c(3, 2, 448), label = "stoveuseminutes_solids", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    minutesClean = structure(c(0, 0, 0), label = "stoveuseminutes_clean", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    stoveClean = structure(c(0, 0, 0), label = "stove_clean", format.stata = "%9.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), label = "Written by R.")
```

This is how the code looks like:

```
  all_summary <- allcountries %>%
 select(Country, head_gender, female_educ, male_educ, w_visitpeople, w_vismarket, w_leavevill,    fridge_owned_desired, radio_owned_desired, fan_owned_desired, pc_owned_desired, tv_owned_desired, stoveuseminutes_solids, stoveuseminutes_clean, stove_clean) %>%
rename(country = Country,
     headGender = head_gender,
     femaleEduc = female_educ,
     maleEduc = male_educ,
     wVispeople = w_visitpeople,
     wVismarket = w_vismarket,
     wLeavevill = w_leavevill,
     fridge = fridge_owned_desired,
     radio = radio_owned_desired,
     fan = fan_owned_desired,
     pc = pc_owned_desired,
     tv = tv_owned_desired,
     minutesSolid = stoveuseminutes_solids,
     minutesClean = stoveuseminutes_clean,
     stoveClean = stove_clean)

#Group by country
all_summary_grouped <- all_summary %>%  group_by(country)

sumstats_all_grouped <-
   all_summary_grouped %>%
   summarise_each(funs(
   n = sum(!is.na(.)),
   min = min(., na.rm = TRUE),
   max = max(., na.rm = TRUE),
   mean = mean(., na.rm = TRUE)
   ))

#Reshape data
sumstatsA <- sumstats_all_grouped %>%
gather(stat, val) %>%
separate(stat, into = c ("var", "stat"), sep = "_") %>%
spread(stat, val)  %>%
select(var, n, min, max, mean)

 #Round
 sumstatsA = sumstatsA %>%
 mutate(mean = round(as.numeric(mean),2))

#produce table
stargazer(
sumstatsA, 
summary = F, 
type = "text", 
digits = 2, 
header = F , 
title = "Summary statistics for Honduras, Nepal and Rwanda", 
rownames = F, 
out = "Manuscript/Tables/SummaryAll_grouped.tex")
```

The error happens after the #Reshape data command section
(Error in `spread()`:
! Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 171 rows:

- 112, 113, 114
- 91, 92, 93
- 106, 107, 108
  (to be continued))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite R forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: The usual caveat: don’t use ‘stargazer’ because [‘stargazer’ is an utterly atrocious package](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/6o9v9h/comment/dkgw9q1/). Use ‘[modelsummary](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/)’ or ‘[texreg](https://github.com/leifeld/texreg/)’ instead, or literally anything else.

Comment: I would advice you to let the summary packages calculate summary statistics, instead of doing it manually in tidyverse. Is .tex your designated output format? Basically, you like to have basic descriptive statistics (n, mean, min, max) for country grouped data?

Comment: Dear Konrad, Dear Marco, thank you so much for all the nice ideas, I would use the next days to try them out and comment back if they worked out for me. @Marco: yes my output format is tex and I would like to get basic descriptive statistics, maybe in addition I would like to get the median.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some minimal raw data:

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)
as_tibble(mtcars)

# A tibble: 32 × 11
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# … with 22 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

This is the `gtsummary` package that produces easy summary statistics per group (e.g. `cyl`) in default html format (you can have various modifications for the table):

```
library(gtsummary)
mtcars %>% tbl_summary(by = cyl)
```

[image]

There are options to print this as .tex:

```
# print as tex
as_kable_extra(mtcars %>% tbl_summary(by = cyl), format = "latex")

\begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c}
\hline
\textbf{Characteristic} & \textbf{4}, N = 11 & \textbf{6}, N = 7 & \textbf{8}, N = 14\\
\hline
mpg & 26.0 (22.8, 30.4) & 19.7 (18.6, 21.0) & 15.2 (14.4, 16.2)\\
\hline
disp & 108 (79, 121) & 168 (160, 196) & 350 (302, 390)\\
\hline
hp & 91 (66, 96) & 110 (110, 123) & 192 (176, 241)\\
\hline
drat & 4.08 (3.81, 4.16) & 3.90 (3.35, 3.91) & 3.12 (3.07, 3.22)\\
\hline
wt & 2.20 (1.89, 2.62) & 3.21 (2.82, 3.44) & 3.76 (3.53, 4.01)\\
\hline
qsec & 18.90 (18.56, 19.95) & 18.30 (16.74, 19.17) & 17.18 (16.10, 17.56)\\
\hline
vs & 10 (91\%) & 4 (57\%) & 0 (0\%)\\
\hline
am & 8 (73\%) & 3 (43\%) & 2 (14\%)\\
\hline
gear &  &  & \\
\hline
\hspace{1em}3 & 1 (9.1\%) & 2 (29\%) & 12 (86\%)\\
\hline
\hspace{1em}4 & 8 (73\%) & 4 (57\%) & 0 (0\%)\\
\hline
\hspace{1em}5 & 2 (18\%) & 1 (14\%) & 2 (14\%)\\
\hline
carb &  &  & \\
\hline
\hspace{1em}1 & 5 (45\%) & 2 (29\%) & 0 (0\%)\\
\hline
\hspace{1em}2 & 6 (55\%) & 0 (0\%) & 4 (29\%)\\
\hline
\hspace{1em}3 & 0 (0\%) & 0 (0\%) & 3 (21\%)\\
\hline
\hspace{1em}4 & 0 (0\%) & 4 (57\%) & 6 (43\%)\\
\hline
\hspace{1em}6 & 0 (0\%) & 1 (14\%) & 0 (0\%)\\
\hline
\hspace{1em}8 & 0 (0\%) & 0 (0\%) & 1 (7.1\%)\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\rule{0pt}{1em}\textsuperscript{1} Median (IQR); n (\%)}\\
\end{tabular}
```

**Update**

Here is a list of various statistics that you can specify via options. It now shows the number of non-missings, the mean, the median, p25 and p75 and the range from min to max.

```
mtcars %>% tbl_summary(by = am,
                       type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2",
                       statistic = all_continuous() ~ c(
                         "{N_nonmiss}",
                         "{mean}",
                         "{median} ({p25}, {p75})",
                         "{min}, {max}"
                       ))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, the .tex table looks really nice, thank you!

Comment: I just have two more small questions. Is there the possibility to safe the table as .tex file like with `stargazer`? and the other question would be, is there an option to change the names of the variables? I renamed `rename` them before, but for some reason the command `as_kable_extra(mtcars %>% tbl_summary(by = cyl), format = "latex")` together with the updated command uses the old names of the variables.

Comment: Are you sure you used `rename` and stored the result in the data? Like `mtcars <- mtcars %>% rename(new = old)`.

Comment: See this post to save the output to a file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67326408/save-as-kable-extra-format-latex-on-file with `write_lines` from `readr`

Comment: Dear Marco, thank you! I could generate a tex. file!

Comment: Considering the ´rename´ command I could not find a solution. The problem is persistent. After I rename the variables in the dataset R keeps showing me two names when I click to view the dataset. The heading is the new name, the "subtitle" is the old name. When producing the tex. file the old name is used. I also tried ´transmute´ and ´mutate´ to change the names in the dataset.

Comment: Ulli, I recommend to ask a new question with regard renaming variables. Provide a minimal example of your data. I think your first issue was solved, to basically create a grouped statistic and export it to .tex We are looking forward to support you with the renaming issue.